# Its possible play stereoscopic 360 video on EasyMovieTexture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

Actually, I can play 360 mono videos on EasyMovieTexture, but now I need to know if, Is possible to play stereoscopic videos? and if is it, how can this be done?

Comment: what platform are you building for?

Comment: @lockstock I'm using Samsung gear VR

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and it is fairly easy.

You need to create two layers, one for the left eye, one for the right eye.
Then, you duplicate both your camera and your spherical screen.

One sphere should be on the Left-Eye layer, and the other on the Right-Eye layer.
Then, you configure your cameras like so:

[image: camera settings]

This is the right camera. So the *Culling Mask* has the Lef-Eye layer disabled and the *Target Eye* is set to Right. You need to do the opposite with the left camera.

Note that both spheres and both cameras should be at the exact same position. The *Stereo Separation* is done automatically and can be configured on your cameras. (You can just keep the default values)

Alright so just one last thing, you need to configure your materials on each sphere to show only one side of the video.

Here is an example for side-by-side stereoscopy. You can easily adapt that to handle top-bottom stereoscopy.

[image: stereo mat left]
[image: stereo mat right]